# Pythonで同じものを繰り返し出力させることができません。

Tags: python, python3

Python初心者です。
`Hello,World!`と100回打つのに、対話シェルのエディタで

```
for i in range(100):
        print("Hello, World!")
```

と書けば100回出力されると本に書いてあったのですが、全く同じコードを書いても100回どころか何も表示されません。
プログラムであるとそもそも読み取ってくれていないのでしょうか？

Comment: 提示されたコードでは2行目が半角の空白が8文字分ありますが、4文字分にするとどうなりますか？

Comment: スクリーンショットの方が回答者に状況が伝わりやすいかもしれません

Comment: もしかして、print 文を入力した後にReturnキー(もしくはEnterキー)を一度だけしか押していないでしょうか？ その場合、インタラクティブシェルでは for 文が続いていると判断されますので、もう一度 Return or Enter キーを押す(空行を入力する)事で for 文が完結したと見做されて for 文全体の実行が開始されます。

Comment: Enterキーを押していなかったのが原因でした。助けてくださって本当にありがとうございました。